# Why do I keep getting mysql error 1042?

Tags: server, apache2, mysql

I'm creating an ASP.NET web api on a linux VPS, using Apache and mod_mono.  I have everything set up and have successfully demonstrated that the web api routes are working.

My newest local changes add integration with a mysql database.  On my development machine, this works perfectly.  However, whenever I upload the published API, the connection to the database fails. I did some digging and realized that the exception being thrown reports error 1042 - Can't get hostname for your address.

Here's my connection string:

`SERVER={0};DATABASE={1};UID={2};PASSWORD={3};` (server is localhost, and other values are filled in appropriately).

What am I doing wrong? How can I get it to connect to mysql?  I have no problems connecting from the same account I'm trying to use when I'm ssh'ed in on my admin account...

EDIT:

I've tried putting `skip-name-resolve` in /var/mysql/my.cnf, but it didn't do anything.  I've also tried flushing hosts in mysql.

Comment: Have you tried replacing "localhost" with the actual IP address of the server? That would skip the name resolving step.

Comment: I've tried that.  Same result.

Comment: Actually, I take that back, @Jos.  When I put in the actual IP of the server I'm on, I get a different error - mysql error 0, which means it cannot connect to the server.  I figured that this was a worse error than before, so I didn't pursue this avenue any further.  Is this better than where I was before?

Comment: I think so, yes. I suspect that your API now tries to connect to the right server address, but can't connect for different reasons, e.g. because the MySQL server doesn't allow connections over the network (which it doesn't by default). Just to verify: you built your API on a local machine with a local database; now the API runs on a different (remote) machine which has its own database server. Is that correct?

Comment: This is correct. How can I enable connections over network?

Comment: After changing `bind-address` to `0.0.0.0`, I can get mysql 0 with the connection string `UID={0};PASSWORD={1};`

Comment: I suggest you simply google "mysql enable network access". You can easily test it by ssh'ing to the server and doing `mysql -h IP-ADDRESS -u USERNAME -p`.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly which part of this troubleshooting process fixed the issue, but my web api can connect to MySql now.  I appreciate your help; if you write up an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API doesn't seem to properly resolve the "localhost" part of the database connection string. If you replace "localhost" with the IP address, it can connect to the server over the network, thereby skipping the resolve part.

However, your MySQL server needs to allow access over the network. That is a non-default setting, for which ample help is available elsewhere on this site.

Keep in mind that you have now hard-coded the IP address into the API software. Make sure that the software keeps functioning even after a network change, e.g. by replacing the IP address by a proper host name.